# LHAPDF: undefined symbol when running in Python

Tags: python, c++, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I'm trying to use the Python interface for [LHAPDF](https://lhapdf.hepforge.org/install.html#pyext), but I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lhapdf
ImportError: /home/n17182559/LHAPDF/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lhapdf.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6LHAPDF6ConfigD1Ev
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 17.04, using Python 2.7, have Boost installed and have a working C++ compiler (g++). I believe I have successfully installed LHAPDF, as I followed the instructions on their website and got no error message (only warnings that auto_ptr is deprecated, but I don't think I have control over that). I did add the ~/LHAPDF/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/ directory to $PYTHONPATH and ~/LHAPDF/bin/ directory to $PATH. I am using LHAPDF 6.1.6 (latest version as of writing this).

I get this error message from a test.py file that merely contains

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lhapdf
```

If it can help you help me, I have found someone with a [similar problem](https://github.com/davidchall/homebrew-hep/issues/39), but the cause seems not to be the same thing (I don't have Anaconda installed). As they solved their problem by removing Anaconda from $PATH, here are my $PATH and $PYTHONPATH as they might be the source of the problem (although I don't see how):

```
$PATH
/home/n17182559/LHAPDF/bin:/opt/applications/geant4/geant4.10.02-install/bin:/home/n17182559/ROOT/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:

$PYTHONPATH
/home/n17182559/ROOT/lib:/home/n17182559/LHAPDF/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: The problem was that the main LHAPDF lib directory was not linked to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/LHAPDF/lib/libLHAPDF.so solved it, if anyone needs the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it (with external help), if anyone wants the solution. The problem was that the main LHAPDF lib directory was not linked to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This command line solved it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/LHAPDF/lib/libLHAP‌​DF.so
```

(which I added to my ~/.bashrc file).

Comment: Great!  I was hoping it would be this direct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your specific problem, but when I get this class of error, it stems from a version mismatch between packages: `lhapdf` depends on another package to define that arcane "semi-hidden" symbol, but the package on which it depends is of a version different from the one expected; the older/newer version doesn't provide that symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just going to try that, but then someone else (outside of stackoverflow) told me what the problem was and it is now solved (see my comment on original post).

Comment: Excellent!  Please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.  We want this to serve as a repository of useful, searchable answers.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips! I actually upvoted your answer as it was quick, related and useful to someone who might have a similar problem, but my upvote doesn't appear because my reputation is still too low :P.

Comment: I know; you have to hit 50 points, I think.  As poster, you should still *accept* your answer.

Comment: Yes I just did that, I had to wait a day to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a version mismatch (of Python), which is likely caused by upgrading Python after LHAPDF is installed.

Therefore you may have to reinstall LHAPDF, or you could install a second LHAPDF if you use two versions of Python (as of now I am not aware of a solution other than this).

Let us assume you use LHAPDF of version 6.2 or higher, which is much simpler. First you would like to set the path in your shell profile so that it points to the version of Python you want to install LHAPDF for. For `bash`, you could do

```sh
export PATH=path/to/python
```

then you would like to follow the [instruction](https://lhapdf.hepforge.org/install.html) and do

```sh
tar xf LHAPDF-6.X.Y.tar.gz
cd LHAPDF-6.X.Y
./configure --prefix=/path/for/installation
make
make install
```

After the installation is done, you can add LHAPDF to the path by

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=path/to/lhapdf/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/lhapdf/lib
export PATH=path/to/lhapdf/bin/:$PATH
export LHAPDF_DATA_PATH=path/to/lhapdf/share/LHAPDF
```